# What is a 'SAM type' in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, terminology

Reading up on the Java-8 spec, I keep seeing references to 'SAM types'. I haven't been able to find a clear explanation of what this is.

What is a SAM type and what is an example scenario of when one might be used?

Comment: See http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-3.html (which I found after a single search, which took me to another SO question).

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. Thanks! Just out of curiosity, what keyword did you use in your search?

Comment: Please don't refer people to out-of-date information.  A slightly longer search would have taken you to the more up-to-date version: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html, which itself is 18 months old and now outdated in many places. The OP's question is answered at http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-a-functional-interface/, one page in an FAQ which I try to keep up to date in what has been until recently a rapidly-changing language and API development.

Comment: @MauriceNaftalin You could also just link [the Java trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), which is kept up to date by the development team.

Comment: The current term is "functional interface".

Comment: @MauriceNaftalin: Sorry, missed that one. Would certainly have linked to it if I'd found that.

Comment: the "final" state of the lambda link: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html

Answer (score 185, accepted):

To summarize [the link Jon posted](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-3.html)<sup>1</sup> in case it ever goes down, "SAM" stands for "single abstract method", and "SAM-type" refers to interfaces like `Runnable`, `Callable`, etc. Lambda expressions, a new feature in Java 8, are considered a SAM type and can be freely converted to them.

For example, with an interface like this:

```
public interface Callable<T> {
    public T call();
}
```

You can declare a `Callable` using lambda expressions like this:

```
Callable<String> strCallable = () -> "Hello world!";
System.out.println(strCallable.call()); // prints "Hello world!"
```

Lambda expressions in this context are mostly just syntactic sugar. They look better in code than anonymous classes and are less restrictive on method naming. Take this example from the link:

```
class Person { 
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public static int compareByAge(Person a, Person b) { ... }

    public static int compareByName(Person a, Person b) { ... }
}

Person[] people = ...
Arrays.sort(people, Person::compareByAge);
```

This creates a `Comparator` using a specific method that doesn't share the same name as `Comparator.compare`, that way you don't have to follow the interface naming of methods and you can have multiple comparison overrides in a class, then create the comparators on the fly via the lambda expressions.

**Going Deeper...**

On a deeper level, Java implements these using the `invokedynamic` bytecode instruction added in Java 7. I said earlier that declaring a Lambda creates an instance of `Callable` or `Comparable` similar to an anonymous class, but that's not *strictly* true. Instead, the first time the `invokedynamic` is called, it creates a Lambda function handler using the [`LambdaMetafactory.metafactory` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-), then uses this cached instance in future invocations of the Lambda. More info can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30002627/646634).

This approach is complex and even includes code that can read primitive values and references directly from stack memory to pass into your Lambda code (e.g. to get around needing to allocate an `Object[]` array to invoke your Lambda), but it allows future iterations of the Lambda implementation to replace old implementations without having to worry about bytecode compatibility. If the engineers at Oracle change the underlying Lambda implementation in a newer version of the JVM, Lambdas compiled on an older JVM will automatically use the newer implementation without any changes on the developer's part.

---

<sup>1</sup> The syntax on the link is out of date. Take a look at the [Lambda Expressions Java Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to see the current syntax.