# What's the type of a method reference?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

Say we have

```
class A {
   B method1 (C c) { ... }
}
```

What's the type of method1 as a method reference?

This is, what's the method signature of `foo()` for this call?:

```
foo (A::method1);
```

Note:

I've defined an interface

```
interface I {
   B m (A a, C c);
}
```

and it seems it is right to declare foo as

```
void foo (I i) { }
```

(since it matches the call `foo(A::method1)` 
--inside `foo` you have to write `b=i.m(a,c)` to mean `b=a.method1(c)`).

Is this the only way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method references and lambdas are target-typed to match [SAM interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17913409/1362755). In your case it has to match `I` because that's the type of `foo`'s argument.

Answer (score 1):

Informal explanation:

Remember that method references can be thought of as an alternate syntax for some lambdas, and that lambdas all implement one or more [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).

And remember that lambdas are (currently) a way to write some single-method anonymous classes in a much more concise form; thus, lambdas can always be reduced to a anonymous class (but not always the other way around).

So

```
foo (A::method1);
```

can become

```
foo ((c) -> <body>);
```

which can be reduced to the anonymous class:

```
foo (new Function<B>() {
    <body>
});
```

which is an anonymous class that is a subtype of Function

Method references are thus anonymous subtypes of whatever functional interface they represent, and so the type of the parameter has to be the corresponding functional interface or one of its supertypes.

---

The JLS actually has a section titled "15.13.2. Type of a Method Reference", but the wording might be a bit obtuse. In short:

A method reference can be used as a type `T` if:

- `T` is a functional interface type (section 9.8)
- The functional interface's abstract method matches the compile-time type of the method reference
- Either:

  - The reference returns `void`
  - The reference returns a type that can be assigned to the corresponding type of the functional interface, e.g. A method reference has to return `Number` or a subtype to be compatible with `B foo(Function f)

Comment: it's not equivalent to anonymous inner classes because lambdas do not capture $this as a field

Comment: @the8472 Ah, didn't know about that. Took a stab at a fixing it, hopefully it isn't wrong. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring the new interface you may use an existing [`BiFunction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html):

```
void foo(BiFunction<? super A, ? super C, ? extends B> fn) {
    ...
    B b = fn.apply(a, c);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am admitting here that this question is too complex for me to answer without trying, but I have tried to understand your question hence providing my understanding of this situation - Your approach is fine. Basically you are doing the following things here -

1. Using shorthand syntax for having an anonymous class which implements the **functional interface** - which is fine.
2. Let the compiler know to use `A::method1` as the implementation of `I.m`  - which is fine as well.
3. Because `A::method1` is already existing you can use method reference instead of lambda expression -  - which is fine as well.
4. Passing of actual parameter `c` which is done in the body of `foo` method in the line - `b=i.m(a,c)`. The actual parameter used here for `c` should get passed to `A::method1`.
5. Object `a` in `a.method1` remains **arbitrary** as per java 8 specification for this syntax as you specifying `Class::Method` and not `Instance::Method`