# Java 8: replace anonymous class with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm having problem in replacing this particular example:

```
Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
            throws IOException {
        String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
    }
};
```

Is it possible to replace that with lambda as it uses non-default constructor for DefaultConsumer?

It's from rabbitMQ java tutorial -> [LINK to whole class](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/java/Recv.java)

Comment: It depends on `DefaultConsumer`. Is there more than one abstract method ? How are you using `Consumer consumer` ?

Comment: @AxelH https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/DefaultConsumer.html

Comment: @slim, thanks, that's answer my questions, nope it can't be used for it!

Comment: If you do this for _multiple_ `DefaultConsumer`s though, you could create a helper method, taking a `lambda` as input and returning an anonymous subclass of `Defaultconsumer`.

Answer (score 7):

No you can't. [DefaultConsumer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/DefaultConsumer.html) is not a [FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html?is-external=true) (and can't be: [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913409/what-is-a-sam-type-in-java)) hence is not a lambda target.

**Explanation:**

### Can *every* anonymous class be replaced by a lambda expression?

The answer is no. You can create an anonymous class for non-final classes and interfaces. Is not the same for lambda expressions. These can be only used where a SAM interface is expected, i.e. interfaces with only a *Single Abstract Method* (before Java 8 every interface method was abstract but since Java 8 interfaces can also have default and static methods which aren't abstract because they have implementation).

### So which anonymous classes can be replaced with a lambda expression?

Only anonymous classes which are implementations of a SAM interface (like Runnable, ActionListener, Comparator, Predicate) can be replaced by a lambda expression. DefaultConsumer cannot be a lambda target because is not even an Interface.

### And what about Consumer?

Even though [Consumer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/Consumer.html) is an Interface, it is not a SAM Interface because it has more than 1 abstract method so it can't be a lambda target either.

Comment: Doesn't change much on the result here but [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) is not mandatory .

Comment: An interface can be a "functional interface" without being annotated `@FunctionInterface` -- but `DefaultConsumer` is not a functional interface for a number of reasons -- not an interface; multiple methods none of which is abstract...

Comment: @AxelH I know but it needs to be a [SAM type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913409/what-is-a-sam-type-in-java) anyway to be a lamda target

Comment: I know, that's why this _"doesn't change much on the result"_ ;) but the explanation is a bit broad, I prefer your comment as an explanation. Because your answer don't do the difference between "is not a `FunctionnalInterface`" and "**can not be** a `FunctionnalInterface`" since the annotation itself is optional.

Comment: @AxelH understood. Edited my answer.