# How referece MyClass::new in scala code?

Tags: java, scala

Here is java version:

```
Optional<Object> optionalFramework = Optional.empty();

optionalFramework.orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
```

How to rewrite this in scala? (Note **with** using `java.util.Optional` not scala `Option`) How replace `IllegalStateException::new` in scala?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Scala 2.12.x, you can use a [SAM type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913409/what-is-a-sam-type-in-java):

```
val a = Optional.of(10)
a.orElseThrow(() => new IllegalStateException("Can't do that"))
```

Otherwise, you'll need to implement the full `Supplier` interface:

```
a.orElseThrow(new Supplier[Throwable] {
  override def get(): Throwable = new IllegalStateException("Nope")
})
```

There's no exact equivalent syntax for Method Reference in Scala, it is similar to the syntax of a lambda expression, but not quite.