# How a Comparator is created from method reference?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm learning about lambda expressions. I don't understand how a comparator is returned from method reference.

I want to sort a list of persons by age.

To do that, I have a method to find the age difference:

```
public int ageDifference(final Person other) {
    return age - other.age;
}
```

The `sorted` method needs as parameter a `Comparator`

```
Stream<T> sorted(Comparator<? super T> comparator);
```

My lambda expression is:

```
people.stream()
.sorted(Person::ageDifference)
.collect(toList());
```

How `Person::ageDifference` is trasformed in a `Comparator<Person>`?

My complete example:

```
public class Person {

private final String name;
private final int age;

public Person(final String theName, final int theAge) {
    name = theName;
    age = theAge;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public int ageDifference(final Person other) {
    return age - other.age;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s - %d", name, age);
}

public static void main (String args[] ){
    final List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("John", 10),
            new Person("Greg", 30),
            new Person("Sara", 20),
            new Person("Jane", 15));

    List<Person> ascendingAge =
            people.stream()
                    .sorted(Person::ageDifference)
                    .collect(toList());

    System.out.println(ascendingAge);
}
}
```

Output: `[John - 10, Jane - 15, Sara - 20, Greg - 30]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913409/what-is-a-sam-type-in-java

Comment: Right, `Comparator` is a SAM type.  A Single Abstract Method.  So the compiler "just knows" to substitute the `Comparator` type and have it call the method you supply, `Person::ageDifference`.  The link Leonard Kraemer supplied explains in more detail.

Comment: As a lambda it'd look like: `(p1, p2) -> p1.ageDifference(p2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your main confusion is this:

> `Comparator<T>` represents a method that takes two parameters of type `T` and returns a `int`. My `ageDifference` method accepts only one `Person` parameter. How can that become a `Comparator<Person>`?

Note that `ageDifference` is an instance method. To call it, not only do you need the parameters, you also need an instance of `Person`. In this case, you need 2 `Person`s to call the method - one on which you call `ageDifference`, and the other one you pass as a parameter:

```
me.ageDifference(someoneElse)
^                      ^
|                      |
        Two people!
```

Isn't this *just like* a `static` method that accepts two parameters?

Therefore, Java is smart enough to know that you need two people to call `Person::ageDifference`, so the method reference is treated as having two parameters.

In general, an instance method of a class `T` accepting parameters `P1`, `P2` ... `Pn` and returning type `R` can be treated as a static method accepting parameters `T`, `P1`, `P2` ... `Pn` and returning `R`.

Comment: to complete your good answer, the reason why the code above compiles is in the way of how the new lambda functionality works in Java 8. It relies on a concept which is informally known as "single abstract method (SAM)" interfaces. The basic idea is that any interface with one abstract method can be automatically implemented by any lambda or method reference, if the lambda or method reference matches the SAM in the interface.