# Implement count down timer on scala

Tags: scala, timer

How can implement count dow `Timer` on scala ?
All i want to timer that count back 10 seconds before continue in my method.

All i found is this `Stopwatch`:

package views

```
class Stopwatch {
  var start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  def elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
  def printElapsed(msg: String) = {
    val delta = elapsed
    new Thread(new Runnable {
      def run = {
        System.out.println(msg + " time ellapsed: " + delta + "ms")
      }
    }).start()
  }
  def restart = {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis()
      new Thread(new Runnable {
      def run = {
        System.out.println("------restart------")
      }
    }).start()
  }
}
```

Comment: If all you want is a delay, look into `Thread.sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want proper non-blocking execution your program will have to be structured special way to support it. Whether you use Akka [scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/scheduler.html):

```
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(50 milliseconds) { 
  // call the rest of your method
}
```

or `Future`/`Promise` - a promise that never completes and you execute it with duration of 10 seconds.

If that's an overkill and you don't mind blocking use `Thread.sleep(10000)` - your thread will be wasted for that time. Similar blocking solution is: [Scala - ScheduledFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359849/scala-scheduledfuture).